# how to connect to Quickbooks hosted on Rightnetworks

Tags: quickbooks

I already built quickbooks integration using new QuickBooks apiv3.
One of my client's quickbook is hosted on rightnetworks.

how to connect to hosted quickbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
how to connect to Quickbooks hosted on Rightnetworks
```

The same way you connect QuickBooks on any other computer. There's nothing special or different about what Right Networks is doing, they are just making QuickBooks available via Remote Desktop.

If QuickBooks was on your own computer, you'd pop open Sync Manager and punch in your username/password.

On RightNetworks, you do the exact same thing.